# pipline не видит системных переменных на моем компьютере

Tags: gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция, gitlab-runner

Я работаю в gitlab, пишу pipline, и я сделал ранером свой компьютер. При запуске pipline выходят ошибки такого рода:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я изначально у меня выдавалась такая же ошибка на python --version. Но потом оказалось что вообще никакие команды не работают. У меня установлены все утилиты и они прописанны в мой путь на компьютере, но я так понял pipline их не видит. Как можно это исправить?

у меня на компьютере стоит и powrshall 7 и powrshall 5. В config.tomb стоит shell = "pwsh".